# state to hide show component, no value in state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to hide and show components depending on the value selected in my select list.

Im my root app.js I have:

```
   logChange(val) {
      console.log("Selected: " + val);
      this.setState({ active: val });
    }


  render() {

    let options = [
      { value: 'Apprentice', label: 'Apprentice' },
      { value: 'Assessor', label: 'Assessor' },
      { value: 'Assessment Centre', label: 'Assessment Centre' }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="container">

          <User showDiv={this.logChange} />

           {
          this.state.active = "Apprentice"
            ? <Apprentice />
            : null
           }

              {
          this.state.active = "Assessor"
            ? <Assessor />
            : null
           }

          {
          this.state.active = "Assessment Centre"
            ? <AssessmentCenter />
            : null
           }



      </div>
```

User.js component:

```
logChange(userType) {
  this.props.showDiv(userType.value);
}
```

How can I check for the state and render the appropriate componenet?

I dont see a value in the state:
[image]

Comment: All of your ternary operators are using `=` for comparisons when you should be doing `==` or `===`

Comment: I dont see u bindind the logChange function

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
{ this.state.active === "Apprentice" && <Apprentice /> }

{ this.state.active === "Assessor" && <Assessor /> }

{ this.state.active === "Assessment Centre" && <AssessmentCenter /> }
```